# Why can’t I find the book Cheshbon HaNefesh?

Tags: jewish-books

I have been trying to purchase the books Cheshbon HaNefesh by Rav Menachem Mendel Lefin.

I am seeing one obscure posting on a website I've never used. I’ve never encountered this with a common English Sefer. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Perhaps its a popular choice for before the High Holidays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking for it in English, because the Hebrew one is available everywhere. You can find the English one at zberman, which is a very reputable store: https://zbermanbooks.com/cheshbon-hanefesh-pocket-size-hc (although this may be an older printing).

The newer printing is available at seforim center at https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=8330&L=1

Comment: Thank you so much!